# error C2664: 'cv::Mat::Mat(int,int,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cv::Size' to 'int'

Tags: c++, opencv

This is my first attempt at writing openCv C++ code. 
I am trying to create an image with all pixel values 200, and then draw a line:

```
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()

{



    std::vector<char> dataPtr(40000, 200);
    cv::Point p1(0,0);
    cv::Point p2(200, 200);
    cv::Size size(200,200); 
    cv::Mat image(size, CV_8U, dataPtr);
    if (image.empty()) //check whether the image is valid or not 
     {
          cout << "Error : Image cannot be created..!!" << endl;
          system("pause"); //wait for a key press
          return -1;
     }

    cv::line(image, p1, p2, 'r', 5, 8, 0); 

    namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"

    imshow("MyWindow", image); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

    waitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress
    destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"
    return 0;
}
```

But this gives the error on the line :

```
    cv::Mat image(size, CV_8U, dataPtr);
```

> ```
> Error 3   error C2664: 'cv::Mat::Mat(int,int,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cv::Size' to 'int'  in 2july.cpp    78
> ```

another error is this:

> 1   IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "cv::Mat::Mat" matches the
>   argument list  2july.cpp  78

It is having some issues with the first parameter 'size'. Why it is saying int, when I have nowhere used int?  Why it is so?

Comment: 'size' might be a bad name for it

Comment: @berak so is size1 :-(

Comment: @berak Is there any issue with my last parameter in Mat ? Any type casting required ?

Comment: oh, sorry, i did not see this,  you're right, that should be &(dataPtr[0])  (the address of the 1st elem) . also, vector<uchar> might be more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the specifications on http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html I couldn't find an instance of a constructor for cv::Mat that has cv::Size as its first parameter and has 3 parameters.

I'd change this

```
cv::Mat image(size, CV_8U, dataPtr);
```

to this

```
cv::Mat image(size, CV_8U);
```